# To what extent do LLMs have grammar rules explicitly programmed?

Tags: llm

Is there typically any explicit programming in LLMs that dictates how to form a sentence? Where does the "understanding" come to with regards to references like "rewrite last reply in 2 words"? How does the LLM "know" what is meant by "rewrite"?
How does the LLM produce a correct answer to "What is the tallest mountain in US, respond in five words"?

Is there another layer that parses the request to understand these meta instructions and instructs the token generating mechanism to stop after it generates 5 words, or is there pure statistics behind understanding what is meant by "respond in five words" to produce the expected result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To what extent do LLMs have grammar rules explicitly programmed?

LLMs don't have grammar rules explicitly programmed by humans. However, neural networks can learn to capture structural information about
languages, e.g. see https://aclanthology.org/P19-1356.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.12327.pdf

> Is there typically any explicit programming in LLMs that dictates how to form a sentence?

No.

> Where does the "understanding" come to with regards to references like "rewrite last reply in 2 words"? How does the LLM "know" what is meant by "rewrite"? How does the LLM produce a correct answer to "What is the tallest mountain in US, respond in five words"?

The "understanding" comes learning to predict the next words based on a [very large training set](https://genai.stackexchange.com/a/163/109).

> Is there another layer that parses the request to understand these meta instructions and instructs the token generating mechanism to stop after it generates 5 words, or is there pure statistics behind understanding what is meant by "respond in five words" to produce the expected result?

Pure statistics.

Comment: Confused by this answer. "LLMs do have grammar rules explicitly programmed by humans" seems to contradict with the later 'no's. A citation/details of what explicitly programmed grammar rules exist would improve the question, I think